# exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:'attempt to scroll to invalid index path

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, collectionview

I've create messaging app based on core data. There is one crash in chat controller that I can't fix. I can't find the pattern when it happens, it seems to appear randomly. It happens in the following method:

```
func scrollCollectionToBottom(animated: Bool){
    if self.fetchedResultsControler.sections?.count == 0 {
        return
    }
    if self.fetchedResultsControler.sections![self.fetchedResultsControler.sections!.count - 1].numberOfObjects == 0{
        return
    }
    let lastSection = self.fetchedResultsControler.sections!.count - 1
    let lastItem = self.fetchedResultsControler.sections![lastSection].numberOfObjects - 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(item: lastItem, section: lastSection)
    if animated{
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
            self.collectionViewMessages.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        })
        return
    }
    if group.type == GroupType.privat.rawValue{
        constrHeightCollViewSubj.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
        self.collectionViewMessages.reloadData()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
            self.collectionViewMessages.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
        })
    }
}
```

As I said in some cases I get crash with this exception:
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:'attempt to scroll to invalid index path

Where is my mistake and how to solve it?

Comment: At which line are you getting crash?

Comment: self.collectionViewMessages.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

Comment: Please check your indexPath. you are getting wrong indexPath at that line.

Comment: Are you sure that `self.collectionViewMessages` is in synch with `self.fetchedResultsControler`? You are creating your index path based on one collection object but uses it on another, looks like possible issue to me.

Comment: of course I'm sure. I'm using fetchresultcontroller for collection view data source and it's working good.